# AWS Glue connection fails over SSL to RDS PostgreSQL database but works without SSL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, aws-glue-connection

I have an AWS RDS PostgreSQL database setup that I would like to connect to using AWS glue using JDBC. My setup is simple, I have 1 VPC, 3 DB private subnets with a route for 0.0.0.0/0 that goes to NAT gateway, a security group that contains a self-referenced rule for all TCP ports inbound and an outbound rule that allows all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0.

Using the legacy glue connection tester, when SSL is disabled, the connection works so I know that

1. The JDBC URL is correct
2. The credentials are correct
3. VPC, Subnet, NACL, Security group configurations seems to be ok

However, when I enable SSL, the connection fails with the following message

> Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Check that your VPC/subnet has network access to AWS S3 and the connection definition contains a security group with an outbound port rule which can access S3

Inspired by [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72025737/jdbc-ssl-connection-postgresql-on-aws) and [this aws lightsail article](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-download-ssl-certificate-for-managed-database), I've tried downloading the AWS root certificates of various sorts including the ones bundled with intermediate certificates to an s3 bucket that I own and referencing that as the custom certificate in the glue connection SSL configurations.

I am aware that by default, [AWS RDS databases are provisioned with an SSL cert for its connection endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html), which would mean I should not need to upload a custom cert (if I understand this correctly), but I'm grasping at straws at this point.

Does anyone have any ideas on why the connection is failing over SSL?